# Find the last value after the dot in DAX e.g. in value1.value2.value3 finds value3

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column with a dotted value e.g

```
project.phase.task
project.task
project.phase.subphase.task
```

in each instance I want the last doted value.
I am using the DAX function:

```
lastVal = 
var i = FIND(".",'My Table'[wbs],1,-1)
return
if(i>0,mid('My Table'[wbs],i+1,99),"")
```

There is no FindLast function. How would I simulate it?
This would be a similar problen to finding a file extension in a file name or path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the string into an indexed list of characters and then take the characters after the maximally indexed `.`.

This should work as a calculated column:

```
lastVal =
VAR String = 'My Table'[wbs]
VAR StringLength = LEN ( String )
VAR StringToTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( 1, StringLength ),
        "Char", MID ( String, [Value], 1 )
    )
VAR LastDot = MAXX ( FILTER ( StringToTable, [Char] = "." ), [Value] )
RETURN
    RIGHT ( String, StringLength - LastDot )
```

If you need it as a measure, then simply adjust the `String` variable to take the appropriate aggregate. For example,  `MAX('My Table'[wbs])` or `FIRSTNONBLANK('My Table'[wbs], 'My Table'[wbs])`.

Comment: Thank you Alexis. Exactly what I asked for. The answer also caters for the strange edge case where I have no delimiters and just a last value. I have a lot to learn about DAX.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do this with DAX. You can use `Split Column` function of the `Query Editor` to get the part of the text after the right-most dot.

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer. I used Duplicate Column > Split Column > Remove Column (First part of the split)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with DAX.

As a calculated column:

```
lastVal = 
    PATHITEMREVERSE ( 
        SUBSTITUTE ( 
            'My Table'[wbs],
            ".",
            "|"
        ),
        1
    )
```

As a measure:

```
lastValMeasure = 
VAR MyString = 
    IF ( 
        HASONEVALUE ( 'My Table'[wbs] ),
        FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'My Table'[wbs], 1 ),
        BLANK()
    )
RETURN
    PATHITEMREVERSE ( 
        SUBSTITUTE ( 
            MyString,
            ".",
            "|"
        ),
        1
    )
```

Comment: Clever use of a path function!